# Why won't writeFile work node.js

Tags: node.js

Why won't this call to fs.writeFile work out? I'm on Linux Ubuntu. The call is at the very end of this gulp task, where I try and write a string, which I have verified is correct, over the file. The manifest[key] code is returning the correct file name. It should work unless I'm missing something dumb. Please help! The writefile call is not showing an error. But the file is not written over.

```
gulp.task('injecttags', function() {
const manifest = jsonfile.readFileSync('./public/manifest/manifest.json');

const htmlkeys = [];
Object.keys(manifest).forEach((key) => {
    if (key.endsWith('.html')) {
        htmlkeys.push(key);
    }
});

htmlkeys.forEach((key) => {
    console.log("For key:", key);
    let file_content = fs.readFileSync('./public/html/'+manifest[key]).toString();
    console.log(file_content);
    let position = 0;
    while (((position = file_content.indexOf('<!-- INSERTSCRIPT=', position)) !== -1)) {
        const actualpositiontowriteto = file_content.indexOf('\n', position);
        const openquotepos = file_content.indexOf("'", position) + 1;
        const closequotepos = file_content.indexOf("'", openquotepos);
        const keystr = file_content.substring(openquotepos, closequotepos);
        const toinsert = `<script src="${manifest[keystr]}"></script>\n`;
        const beg = file_content.substr(0, position);
        const end = file_content.substr(actualpositiontowriteto);
        file_content = beg + toinsert + end;
    }
    position = 0;
    while (((position = file_content.indexOf('<!-- INSERTCSS=', position)) !== -1)) {
        const actualpositiontowriteto = file_content.indexOf('\n', position);
        const openquotepos = file_content.indexOf("'", position) + 1;
        const closequotepos = file_content.indexOf("'", openquotepos);
        const keystr = file_content.substring(openquotepos, closequotepos);
        const toinsert = `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${manifest[keystr]}">\n`;
        const beg = file_content.substr(0, position);
        const end = file_content.substr(actualpositiontowriteto);
        file_content = beg + toinsert + end;
    }

    fs.writeFile('./public/html/'+manifest[key], file_content, (err) => {
        if (err) return console.log('error writing file!', err);
        return console.log('successful file write');
    });
});
});
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not much of a description of the problem.  What do you see in the console?  Are you waiting for completion of the write before trying to use its results.  What debugging have you done?  What did you learn while debugging?

Comment: Yes I'm just plainly viewing the file in text editor after running the task. Seems to be same exact file as before the write. Like I expained, I have validated that the various inputs like manifest[key] are correct. It is perplexing that Node says the write was without error, yet there is no write that I can see.

Comment: Then the file it is writing is probably in a different location than what you're looking at.  `fs.writeFile()` doesn't lie.  If it does not report an error and you are sure you are waiting for it to be done, then it will write successfully.  So, maybe `./public/html/'+manifest[key]` isn't exactly where you think it is.

Comment: I was on version 9.x.x of Node now I switched to 8.11.1 and it's the same.

Comment: Sometimes it would visibly write to the file in question, sometimes it doesn't. When I was looping poorly I would get a lot of legit writes but not correct output. I fixed loop and now no write at all. It's so weird lol.

Comment: Bout to just put the Node and Gulp away... I honestly think it's not my fault. Apparently the sequencer for Gulp I'm using is just a hack, but it's best thing I can find...

Comment: What is the best bet for a web dev build system nowadays? Webpack and Gulp seem to have problems. Would love an answer to that.